# How to check if an element of a list is a number?

Tags: python

How can I check if the first element of the list (below) is a number (using some sort of regular expression) in python:

```
temp = ['1', 'abc', 'XYZ', 'test', '1']
```

Many thanks.

Comment: if an answer fits your needs, feel free to green-checkmark it. :-)

Comment: @eruciform : Said the guy with the most votes beside his answer :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
try:
  i = int(temp[0])
except ValueError:
  print "not an integer\n"

try:
  i = float(temp[0])
except ValueError:
  print "not a number\n"
```

If it must be done with a regex:

```
import re
re.match( '^[-+]?(([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?)|(([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+))$', temp[0] )
```

Comment: If you're going to check for any other things inside the try block, make sure you `except ValueError`

Comment: How does this have the most votes? Empty except's, seriously? Edit: Oh, he fixed it now .. still, why can't you use regex as he asked, or one of the built-in functions? This is a code-heavy way

Comment: I'm all for telling him the right thing to do, but you explicitly ignored the part of the question that said "use a regular expression" :)

Comment: @justin: thanks, updated. @stephen: he said "some sort of regex" - I think he just wants a solution...

Comment: You're probably right.  Answers that don't use regex on questions that ask for regex always seem to get a lot of votes :)

Comment: That regex would accept things like "", ".", "-.", "0." which aren't traditionally accepted as numerics (well, "0." is in Python). So, +1 for the non-regex solution, will be faster, too.

Answer (score 4):

If you are just expecting a simple positive number, you can use the isDigit method of Strings.

```
if temp[0].isdigit(): print "It's a number"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions (because you asked):

```
>>> import re
>>> if re.match('\d+', temp[0]): print "it's a number!"
```

Otherwise, just try to parse as an int and catch the exception:

```
>>> int(temp[0])
```

Of course, this all gets (slightly) more complicated if you want floats, negatives, scientific notation, etc.  I'll leave that as an exercise to the asker :)